# How to get the token address if I have the pair address

Tags: web3.js, token, api, address

What is the fastest way of getting the token address, if I already have the pair address for a token?

**For example:**

The pair address of Bonk/SOL is: `3ne4mWqdYuNiYrYZC9TrA3FcfuFdErghH97vNPbjicr1`

And the address of Bonk is: `DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263`

If I have the pair address of Bonk, what would be the fastest way of getting the address of Bonk itself?

Answer (score 3):

Since Orca's Whirlpool account structs are published in their IDL on chain, you can actually just go to this account page on Solana Explorer and see the deserialized LP account data:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/3ne4mWqdYuNiYrYZC9TrA3FcfuFdErghH97vNPbjicr1/anchor-account

[image: Solana Explorer Account Data]

To do this yourself, you'd need to fetch the account data and then deserialize it yourself.
Here's the IDL of the Whirlpool program: https://explorer.solana.com/address/whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc/anchor-program

And an example of how it's serialized in Solana Explorer:
https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/master/app/components/account/AnchorAccountCard.tsx#L10

And a general overview of account deserialization: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/accounts-and-data/how-to-deserialize-account-data-on-solana

I suspect Orca SDK can streamline this for you, but I personally haven't experimented with this:
https://github.com/everlastingsong/tour-de-whirlpool/tree/main/src/EN